# Error "MediaCodec: mapFormat: no mediaType information" when I was loaded rewarded ad

Tags: ads, media-type, admob-rewardedvideoad

I implement rewarded ads. When rewarded ad loaded start a circling error(trace log in img). I have read and done all tips about working with rewarded ads (MobileAds) but it still won't work. In a project was implemented banner ads and native ads work correctly (all of them on one AdMob account). This is the trace list:
[image: ads have loaded and started error]

Method "show" didn't calling yet.

I was trying all the tips which I founded in internet, but they didn't work for me. I want to implement rewarded ads in my project.